# Why might VMWare Tools downgrade after upgrade?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-tools

Running vSphere Client 5.5 and attempting to upgrade linux VMs that were on the older VMWare tools version. All linux VMs are RedHat v5.0. I go through the VMWare automatic install process and everything completes as expected. Run VMWare tools version check on the command line on my linux box and get the new version. However, overnight something happens (not sure what) and the tools downgrade to their prior version on all linux boxes.

I've tried the VMWare tools auto upgrade from vSphere client, the manual upgrade, all seem to work fine with no error messages and ultimately end up with the right version right after the upgrade, but after so many hours it seems to revert back to the old version. This only happens on my linux VMs as all the old versions on windows VMs are upgrading fine and keeping their upgrade. I've looked in logs in both vSphere tasks and RedHat system logs and neither seem to have anything that would indicate a trigger of this sort of downgrade.

Comment: Are these boxes managed via puppet or some other configuration management tool?  Perhaps that is reverting it?

Comment: Do you have any old update manager baseline running automatically or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoredache provided the angle I needed to take - CFEngine was running on the machine and a process was setup to ensure VMWare tools was installed.

Answer (score 2):

The vSphere client you use doesn't matter. If you install the VMwareTools from the client, afaik the version will depend on the package the ESXi the VM runs on provides.

Anyway, to the best of my knowledge VMwareTools don't install/upgrade/downgrade themselves. As Zoredache points out, check that there isn't any configuration management solution like puppet (chef, cfengine, some cronjob... whatever) enforce a specific version.